# Using root functions inside of prop object

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm using Vuejs2.

I have a prop that contains some validation. I want to use a `Lang` object that is mixed into all my components.  One of my props has a default value that needs to access this lang object.  I can access the lang object in the `create()` function but not in the `props.foo.default()` option.

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import messages from '../lang/messages';
import lang from 'lang.js';

const Lang = new lang({
    'messages': messages,
    'locale': 'en'
});

Vue.mixin({
        data: function () {
            return {
                lang: Lang
            }
        }
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

bar.component.vue

```
<template>
    <div>{{ foo }}</div>
</template>

<script>    
    export default {
        props: {
            foo: {
                type: String,
                default: this.lang.get('some.lang') // Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
            }
        },

        created () {
             console.log(this.lang.get('some.lang'); // returns correct value
        }
    }
</script>
```

So to clarify I can access this.lang inside my `created()` function but I cannot get to it in my props object.

From what I could derive the context of `this` is different depending on the object / function you are in. I've tried to edit the props in the created hook but could not find a way to get access. I managed to get it working by creating a filter but it's inconsistent with some other code that I have in my component.

What would be a good way for a prop to have a default value that can access the root vm or be set outside of the props object?

Comment: I recommend putting stuff you need across many components inside your store (VueX).

Comment: @connexo This is just a simple component that you can pass in a string and the string it's passing in is by no means common, it'll be a string that references a lang.js file.  Thanks for the thought.  Edit: unless you are talking about the lang object?

Comment: I've never seen the way you declare your `props.foo.type` property. Can you link me something about that syntax?

Comment: @connexo Sure.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation

Comment: Ah okay. I expected `props.foo.type` to be a simple String delcared by some ES6/7 sugar I wasn't aware of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a prop's default value based on a data property in a Vue instance. You can't access the Vue instance in the context of the `props` object, and you can't set the default value after the component has been instantiated.

Either import the `lang` object directly into the `bar.component.vue` file:

```
<script>
import lang from 'lang.js'

export default {
  props: {
    foo: {
      type: String,
      default: lang.get('some.lang') 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Or, create a computed property `fooVal` which will return `this.lang.get('some.lang')` if the `foo` prop is not defined, and then use that in your template instead:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ fooVal }}</div>
</template>

<script>    
export default {
  props: {
    foo: { type: String }
  },
  computed: {
    fooVal() {
      return (this.foo === undefined) ? this.lang.get('some.lang') : this.foo;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome. I don't wan't to import it again so I'll use the computed method I think. Thanks for the descriptive answer.